# Libcontainer - Running multiple processes in the container

Tags: go

I am trying to implement something to the effect of `docker run` and `docker exec` using `libcontainer`.

I have been able to create a container and run a process inside it with the following code:

```
func Run(id string, s *specs.LinuxSpec, f *Factory) (int, error) {
    ...
    container, err := f.CreateContainer(id, config)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    process := newProcess(s.Process)
    tty, err := newTty(s.Process.Terminal, process, rootuid)
    defer tty.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    defer func() {
        if derr := Destroy(container); derr != nil {
            err = derr
        }
    }()

    handler := NewSignalHandler(tty)
    defer handler.Close()
    if err := container.Start(process); err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    return handler.forward(process)
}
```

This works great (I believe), but the problem comes when I have to run another process(es) inside the same container. For example, a container is already running (the main process is running in foreground mode): How can I achieve what Docker allows you to do with `docker exec`?

I have the following code:

```
func Exec(container libcontainer.Container, process *libcontainer.Process, onData func(data []byte), onErr func(err error)) (int, error) {
    reader, writer := io.Pipe()
    process.Stdin = os.Stdin

    rootuid, err := container.Config().HostUID()
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    tty, err := newTty(true, process, rootuid)
    defer tty.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    handler := NewSignalHandler(tty)
    defer handler.Close()

    // Redirect process output
    process.Stdout = writer
    process.Stderr = writer

    // Todo: Fix this, it waits for the main process to exit before it starts
    if err := container.Start(process); err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    go func(reader io.Reader) {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            onData(scanner.Bytes())
        }
        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            onErr(err)
        }
    }(reader)

    return handler.forward(process)
}
```

This also works, but the problem is: It waits for the main process to exit before it runs. Sometimes it runs, but my memory goes to `100%` after calling that function 5 - 7 times running a simple `whoami` command.

I'm pretty sure I am doing something(s) wrong, I just don't know what. Or is my understanding of containers failing me?

I used this project as a reference:
https://github.com/opencontainers/runc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably better to use docker as reference for your case, because it uses same `libcontainer.Container` objects for starting and exec new process in container. You can find code interacting with libcontainer here:
https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/daemon/execdriver/native

Also it's better to post whole code, so people could try and debug it to help you.

EDIT:
Here is example code for running multiple containers: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/407eb530c0cb6c87ec9f

I runned it like

```
go run procs.go path-to-busybox
```

You can see with `ps` that there are indeed multiple processes in container.
Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Runc uses the same library (actually it has been taken over by OpenContainers AFAIK) and it was easier to follow than docker. I thought the code will be too long as it is tightly integrated into the app I am working on. Are there specific details I need to include perhaps?

Comment: Minimal runnable example with two processes will be enough. I can try to write example with pure libcontainer if you want.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion: I've been trying to isolate the code for the past 20 minutes, but it's getting too long because it's different packages working together, and the container itself needs a config file which is like an A4 page long. Is there anything you can spot from the code I provided? They are the only code blocks interacting with the container. The approach maybe?

Comment: I added example to answer. Most probably you forgot import nsenter package which is required for entering to containers.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I had to abandon the OpenContainer specification for now though. The project is still very young and under active development. On an unrelated subject, I don't suppose you could update the network section on your example to use a `veth` instead to access internet? I couldn't get it working. Thank you

Comment: You can remove NEWNET from namespaces section and your container will use host network. It shouldn't be too hard to use "veth", you just need to add network to config.Networks. Note that it still requires iptables rules for accessing internet.